# admin controlling login credentials of all users

Tags: php, database, wordpress, authentication

I brought to my superiors a way that we can do our scheduling via a website. Basically the user would log on via there employee username and password and then it will redirect them to a schedule where they can see when they are working. A comments section will also be implemented and other things along the way.

I am highly familiar with Wordpress and the massive amounts of plugins which will aide me with this. Unfortunately the only plugins that I have found are ones that require the user to register first and then log in. How do I go about implementing it so that I can create all the username and passwords on the database and when user is prompted, he/she types in the same credentials as the one I have set up on my end and will successfully login and redirect to the necessary page.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

This plugin seems to be powerful but it appears it doesn't do exactly what I want. I just need some guidance on the next steps on how this can be implemented in a efficient and secure manner.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to import the users, and give them a password initialization process of some sort. The [Import Users from CSV](http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/) plugin seems to do what you want.

Comment: I would prefer them not to go through any  initialization process. If that were the case I would have everyone register...but then I wouldn't necessary know their login credentials.

Comment: You shouldn't know their login credentials. However, as admin you'd be able to change their credentials at any time anyway. Doing an import, however, eliminates the guesswork of "Who's who?" and gives the ability to implement a standard naming protocol and eliminating a couple steps that users would inevitably mess up.